# Using Hibernate framework

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a CITY table(cityId, cityName,status) in MYSQL database. I am using Hibernate framework from my Java program to access the database. Now if I am using a web service in my application, and concurrent user access the web service. One retrieves a City object with cityId=1 while other user tries to update the status of the city with cityId=1.

If a city's status is false it cannot be retrieved. So my question is what will happen if this situation arise? How will Hibernate respond to this?

Comment: What do you mean ifcity' status is false it cannot be retrived? You mean if a city has the status false then the webservice should not show some data to the user accesing the webservice?

Comment: I am just a bit confused as to how are the concurrent transactions being managed by Hibernate? Does Hibernate's cache comes in the scene for maintaining this?

Comment: Here is some documentation https://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/jpa_2_0_concurrency_and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When one user already has the entity "loaded" and someone else is modifying it later,
user one does not "see" this changes.
this is *as far as i remember* the default behaviour of hibernate when there is no special
config or no special "plugin" activated.

I think you can try/check the behaviour by yourself easily.

Comment: Thanks Ben for the reply. I am just a bit confused as to how are the concurrent transactions being managed by Hibernate? Does Hibernate's cache comes in the scene for maintaining this?

Comment: I think the exact behaviour can be configured. the default behaviour is, who saves "last" -> wins! as said, there is also the possibility to add some kind of "locking" behaviour, when entities are loaded. you can try to look for something like Versioning of AuditInterceptors to check the version of the entity before save.